# Can't get if else statement to work in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I wanted to create an animation where a number of images are swapped when you scroll past them. Scrolling down swaps them from 1 to x, up from x to 1. For some reason the else if statements never get past the first and second one...

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var heroBG = $('.hero__background');
        var heroBGTop = heroBG.offset().top;
        var heroImg = heroBG.find('.hero__image');
        var heroImgLength = heroImg.length;
        var heroImgHeight = heroImg.height();
        var interval = heroImgHeight / heroImgLength;
        var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(heroBGTop > windowScrollTop) {
            heroImg.removeClass('hero__image--active')
            heroImg.eq(0).addClass('hero__image--active');
        }
        else if(heroBGTop <= windowScrollTop < (heroBGTop+interval)) {
            heroImg.removeClass('hero__image--active')
            heroImg.eq(1).addClass('hero__image--active');
        }
        else if((heroBGTop+interval) <= windowScrollTop < (heroBGTop+2*interval)) {
            heroImg.removeClass('hero__image--active')
            heroImg.eq(2).addClass('hero__image--active');
        }
        else if((heroBGTop+2*interval) <= windowScrollTop < (heroBGTop+3*interval)) {
            heroImg.removeClass('hero__image--active')
            heroImg.eq(3).addClass('hero__image--active');
        }

    });
```

Comment: What do you think conditions like `heroBGTop <= windowScrollTop < (heroBGTop+interval)` are actually evaluating?  And have you tried debugging those assumptions, eg doing simple tests like `(5 <= 10 < (5+1))` ?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is this: 
if between 0 and 100 show picture 1 
if between 100 and 120 show picture 2
if between 120 and 140 show picture 3

Answer (score 1):

javascript still works your logic is wrong

`heroBGTop <= windowScrollTop < (heroBGTop+interval)`

This command is similar to the following:

`(heroBGTop <= windowScrollTop) < (heroBGTop+interval)` -> `(0 or 1) < (heroBGTop+interval)`

that's so silly!

please change it to:
`heroBGTop <= windowScrollTop && windowScrollTop < (heroBGTop+interval)`

Comment: but i think it still won't work because all esle if 3 and 4 statements have same meaning as 2

Comment: As noted in comment above, the *order* of the `if`s is also relevant.  `if (x > 10 ) .. else if (x<=10) .. else if (any other if won't get hit)`  - hard to tell if this is the case, but likely

Comment: Stating it as && worked, thank you very much!